# get collision-list from dictionary

Tags: c#

Given a dictionary, is it possible to extract a collection of **entries whose keys have the required hashcode**? So the output should be `List<keyValuePair>`.

Each item in my dictionary has an overidden `GetHashCode()` method, which deliberately allows for collisions. It's designed to only work with the item's `name`.

Their `Equals()` function is what resolves these collisions. It checks the `name` and  the `quantity` member variables

inb4: storing a dictionary of lists isn't an option for me

Edit: It needs to be faster than O(n) complexity, ultimatelly like accessing a bucket directly, and making a copy out of it

Comment: Reading your question - I *kind of get* what you're asking, but then you throw things out there without any context or code. Can you edit your question with an example of what you have tried that didn't work?

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . **Why** do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use LINQ to filter the dictionary:

```
var list = dictionary.Where( pair => pair.Value.GetHashCode() == hashCode );
```

This will give you an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T>>`. You can convert it back into a dictionary with `ToDictionary`, of course:

```
var dict = dictionary
    .Where( pair => pair.Value.GetHashCode() == hashCode );
    .ToDictionary( pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value );
```

Comment: Thank you, is this linq query O(n) complexity? If yes, I need something better.  Like literally accessing a bucket, and making a copy of it

Comment: There are no hash buckets for the values in the dictionary, only the keys. You asked for "a collection of objects who have the required hashcode." Did you mean to ask for "the collection of objects whose keys have the required hash code" ?

Comment: I've edited the question - "the collection of entries whose keys have the required hash code". So the output should be List<keyValuePair>.  Preferably O(1)  complexity